# alertmanager won't send out e-mail

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to use "E-mail" to receive alert from Prometheus with alertmanager, however, It is keeping print such log like: "Error on notify: EOF" source="notify.go:283" and "Notify for 3 alerts failed: EOF" source="dispatch.go:261". My alertmanager config is like below:

```
   smtp_smarthost: 'smtp.xxx.com:xxx'
   smtp_from: 'xxxxx@xxx.com'
   smtp_auth_username: 'xxxx@xxx.com'
   smtp_auth_password: 'xxxxxxx'
   smtp_require_tls: false

route:
  group_by: ['instance']
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 7m
  receiver: email
  routes:
  - match:
      severity: critical
      receiver: email
  - match_re:
      severity: ^(warning|critical)$
      receiver: support_team

receivers:
- name: 'email'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'xxxxxx@xx.com'
- name: 'support_team'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'xxxxxx@xx.com'
- name: 'pager'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'alert-pager@example.com'
```

Any suggest?

Comment: Are you using the port `587`? Like, smtp_smarthost: `smtp.gmail.com:587`?

Comment: Yes Kamol， I fixed the issue by altering the port from 465 to 587

Answer (score 2):

I use smtp.xxx.com:587 fixed the issue,but also need to set smtp_require_tls: true

Comment: same here .. Port 587 also worked for me ... just a reminder that you will also need to change on Gmail the following setting  `Security > Less secure app access. Click Turn on access`